# How to call function with input variables in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, undefined

there is two parameters to return Object as JSON

I try to get Posts By Id And attach to Array :

```
// Get Considered Posts, Training, Service, Intall
public function get_considered_posts() {
    $item = new stdclass();
    $item->msg = 'Empty';
    $item->status = false;
    $result = Array();
    $post = $get_post_by_id( 156 ); // Training
    if ( $post ) {
        $result[] = $post ;
    }
    $post = $get_post_by_id( 164 ); // Service
    if ( $post ) {
        $result[] = $post ;
    }

    $post = $get_post_by_id( 161 ); // Intall
    if ( $post ) {
        $result[] = $post ;
    }

    if (count( $result ) == 0 ) {
        $item->msg = 'Empty';
        $item->status = false;
    } else {
        $item->msg = 'Success';
        $item->status = true;
    }
    $item->result = $result;
    return $item;
}
```

Here I want to use Only 5 Properties of Every Post :

```
// Get Post By Id
private function get_post_by_id( $pid ) {
    $post = get_post( $pid = 0 );
    if ( $post ) {
        if ($post->post_status == 'publish') {
            $object = new stdclass();
            $object->id = $post->ID;
            $object->cid = $pid;
            $object->title = $post->post_title;
            $object->content = $post->post_content;
            $object->image = ''.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
            return $object;
        }
    }
    return $post;
}
```

But it shows `500 Internal Server Error`
When I check `error_log` it show :

```
[17-May-2016 14:27:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: get_post_by_id in /home/codypars/public_html/app/wp-webservice/helper.php on line 62
```

[17-May-2016 14:27:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /home/codypars/public_html/app/wp-webservice/helper.php on line 62

How I can fix it ?

---

Solved: thank you [CD-jS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327120/cd-js) And [JustOnUnderMillions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4916265/justonundermillions). To call own functions inside PHP class the right syntax is :

```
this->myFunctionName( $Param1, $Param2, $Param3, ...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the $ from the front of your function names when you're calling them.

e.g.

```
$post = $get_post_by_id( 164 );
```

Should be

```
$post = get_post_by_id( 164 );
```

Comment: And where is `$this->` ??

Comment: Yes, $post = $this->get_post_by_id( 156 ); , Thank You